# Variable returns old value after changing it

Tags: python, pygame

I simply want to draw a triangle using the `pygame.draw.line` method.

I define a function `drawTriangle` that takes the starting x and y coordinates as parameters, puts them in a tuple, then creates two more tuples whose values are dependent on the starting x and y coordinates.

These three points will be the vertices of the triangle. The function then draws 3 lines - from point1 to point2, from point2 to point3, then from point3 back to point1.

The problem is that when I run the program, only one line is being drawn.

```
def drawTriangle(startx, starty):
    point1 = (startx, starty)
    point2 = (startx + 20, starty + 20)
    point3 = (startx -30, starty - 30)

    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, GREEN, point1, point2)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, GREEN, point2, point3)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, GREEN, point3, point1)
```

Comment: Try printing the value of point 1, 2 and 3 before drawing the line but I think your title migth not be the best.

Comment: this won't draw a triangle...

Answer (score 1):

All your points are located on the same line.
May be need:

```
def drawTriangle(startx, starty):
    point1 = (startx, starty)
    point2 = (startx + 20, starty + 20)
    point3 = (startx -30, starty + 30)

    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, GREEN, point1, point2)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, GREEN, point2, point3)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, GREEN, point3, point1)
```

Comment: Im an idiot. I messed around with the points and got a triangle. All my old points were on the same line apparently.

Comment: They were. All your points were of the form `(startx + D, starty +D)` (for D=0, 20, -30), which lie on the line `y=x`.